# How do I keep my GUI objects arrangements reserved when resizing my window?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

When I am resizing my window, all of my panels get compressed and don't show all of the content.

here's my code for my jframe class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;

public class CopyText {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Project 3 Layout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        CopyTextPanel panel = new CopyTextPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and here's my code for my panel arrangement class

```
public class CopyTextPanel extends JPanel {
    private JTextField input;
    private JLabel output, inlabel, outlabel;
    private JButton compute, clear;
    private JPanel panel;

    public CopyTextPanel() {
        inlabel = new JLabel("Input:  ");
        outlabel = new JLabel("Text Statistics Result: ");
        input = new JTextField(50);
        output = new JLabel();
        compute = new JButton("Compute Statistics");
        compute.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        clear = new JButton("Clear Text");
        clear.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        panel = new JPanel();

        //setPreferredSize (new Dimension(700, 150));
        output.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 30));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(620, 100));
        panel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        panel.add(inlabel);
        panel.add(input);
        //panel.add(outlabel);
        //panel.add(output);
        panel.add(compute);
        panel.add(clear);
        panel.add(outlabel);
        panel.add(output);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 150));
        setBackground(Color.blue);
        add(panel);

    }
}
```

ActionEvent class because i feel like that doesn't matter for what I'm trying to accomplish.  Also when I run the program, my outlabel is still above my output, but I'm trying to make it one line with my outlabel output.

Thanks guys!

Comment: A components `minimumSize` will provide hints to the layout managers about how much a component can be compressed. As a general recommendation, you should avoid using `setPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize` as it's to easy for them to be changed, instead preferring to override the getter methods instead.  Also, not all layout managers use these values

Comment: I'm not sure if your comment got cut off or not, but it ended at " you should avoid using setPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize as it"  should I set the panels to minimum size since the rest is already packed?

Comment: that was weird, I went back to this page and I can see your entire comment now.

Comment: Yeah, it got cut off, I finished it :P